# Asterisk unable to lookup hostname

Tags: asterisk

I have an IVR system that runs on the newest Asterisk (13.11.2) with PJSIP enabled.

The system runs smoothly most of the time with no hostname issues. But sometimes it goes crazy with following errors:

[image: errors image]

When I exit out Asterisk while the errors are happening and try to `ping new.ivr` it is successfully resolved to address `127.0.1.1`

Any ideas what could be wrong and how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You should check /etc/resolv.conf and your dns server

You also should check your config for names which not valid dns names like new.ivr and set your hostname to CORRECT dns name.